# JavaFX relocate really slow

Tags: javafx, layout, graph

i have developed a Graph-Editor in JavaFX and now reading a file to build up a graph.

I create around 25000 Cells(Graphnodes) and 22000 edges between them and add them to a Pane which is inside a ScrollPane. After doing this I run a Layout-Algorithm which relocates every cell to a specific point. Relocating the Cells is terribly slow. Every relocate takes around 1 Second.

Does anybody now what could be  the Problem here? Isn't JavaFX capable of showing such an high amount of nodes inside a ScrollPane in a short Time?
What could increase the performance?
Due to the  complexity of the graph I'm not quite able to give a minimal example.

Comment: This is a huge amount of nodes. You should avoid them being handled during a the layout pass (you place them yourself anyways). Setting the `managed` property of all children of the `Pane` to `false` could help. (You could also overwrite the `layoutChildren` method of the `Pane` to speed up layout passes).

Comment: Did you try to cache the nodes? Did you try a cache hint?

Comment: how would caching the nodes work?